# How do I insert place holders in LINQ so that my group has exactly 24 points

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am plotting the 24 hours of a day to a graph but certain hours (like the morning) have no points. How do I change the linq to insert 'Times = 1' when there is no values for that hour ?

So rather than

4, 6, 8, 5, 7, 9...

It would be

1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 6, 8, 5, 7, 9... (24 points always)

```
 Lead[] newLeads;

    newLeads = gameManager.leads.Lead;

    string[] logNumbers = (from nl in newLeads
                           //where DateTime.Parse(nl.CreateDate).Hour > 6
                           select DateTime.Parse(nl.CreateDate).Hour.ToString()
                           ).ToArray();

    var groupedLeads = logNumbers.GroupBy(x => x)
              .Select(x => new { Number = x.Key, Times = x.Count() })
              .ToList();

    //groupedLeads.Add(new { Number = "0", Times = 1 });
    //groupedLeads.Add(new { Number = "1", Times = 1 });
    //groupedLeads.Add(new { Number = "2", Times = 1 });
    //groupedLeads.Add(new { Number = "3", Times = 1 });
    //groupedLeads.Add(new { Number = "4", Times = 1 });
    //groupedLeads.Add(new { Number = "5", Times = 1 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Range` to get your 24h sequence, no need for a `GroupBy`:

```
var hourlyLeads = Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
    .Select(h => new 
    { 
        Hour = h, 
        Count = newLeads.Count(nl => nl.CreateDate.Hour == h) 
    })
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        Number = x.Hour, 
        Times = x.Count == 0 ? 1 : x.Count
    })
    .ToList();
```

---

**Update**

> How could I set the 'current hour' to '1' as well ? I don't want to
>   show the current hour in progress. I could try to delete it from the
>   collection after the linq statement but was wondering if it was easy
>   to do in the current linq statement

Not really clear, but if you want to exclude the current hour:

```
var hourlyLeads = Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
    .Where(h => h != DateTime.Now.Hour)
    .Select(h => new ........
```

If you just want to set the current hour to 1:

```
var hourlyLeads = Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
    .Select(h => new 
    { 
        Hour = h, 
        Count = h == DateTime.Now.Hour ? 1 : newLeads.Count(nl => nl.CreateDate.Hour == h) 
    })
    .Select(x => new .....
```

Comment: How could I set the 'current hour' to '1' as well ? I don't want to show the current hour in progress. I could try to delete it from the collection after the linq statement but was wondering if it was easy to do in the current linq statement

Comment: @punkouter: what means `current hour` here?

Comment: @punkouter: you can't modify it since `DateTime` is a struct. But why do you want it? If you have a `DateTime` and you want to change it's `Hour` property you have to create a new `DateTime`. What do you actually want? Remove current hour from the possible hours or set it's `Times` to 0?

Comment: oops.. I meant set its time to '1' so the entry exists as 'blank'.. So it still contains 24 entries..

Comment: @punkouter: yes, i've noticed it already and edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerable.Range as a source of numbers is an excellent idea.  You can also add a GroupJoin to make the aggregation easy:

```
var hourlyLeads =
  from hour in Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
  group lead in newLeads on hour equals lead.CreateDate.Hour into g
  let count = g.Count()
  select new
  {
    Number = g.Key.ToString(),
    Times = count == 0 ? 1 : count
  };
```